# Azure data factory, stored procedure activity is not updating values in the table but it runs normally in ssms its working as expected wit same input

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The procedure's input is the below one. its a json request to the procedure. in ssms with the same input its correctly updating the table.
the activity and the pipeline is being executed correctly but the update statement is not working in the procedure

```
{
        "source": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSource",
            "sqlReaderStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[UpdateProclaimIDs_test_adf2]",
            "storedProcedureParameters": {
                "p_request_string": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "[[{\"proclaim_id\":1,\"test_patient_id\":1},{\"proclaim_id\":2,\"test_patient_id\":2},{\"proclaim_id\":3,\"test_patient_id\":3},{\"proclaim_id\":4,\"test_patient_id\":4},{\"proclaim_id\":5,\"test_patient_id\":1},{\"proclaim_id\":6,\"test_patient_id\":2},{\"proclaim_id\":7,\"test_patient_id\":3},{\"proclaim_id\":8,\"test_patient_id\":4}]]"
                }
            },
            "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
            "partitionOption": "None"
        },
        "dataset": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
            "type": "DatasetReference",
            "parameters": {}
        }
    }
```

procedure code is

```
alter procedure [dbo].[UpdateProclaimIDs_test_adf2]                                                                                                  
       @p_request_string  nvarchar(max)                                                                                                 
AS                                                                                                  
 BEGIN    
     
  declare @var1 nvarchar(max)= JSON_query(@p_request_string,'$.source.storedProcedureParameters.p_request_string')

  declare @var2 nvarchar(max)= JSON_value(@var1,'$.value')

  --drop table #temp2
   SELECT value
   into #temp2
   FROM OPENJSON(@var2)

     create table #ProclaimIDs    
  (testPatientID int,proclaim_id int) 

  insert into #ProclaimIDs(testPatientID,proclaim_id)
   select test_patient_id,proclaim_id
   from #temp2 
   CROSS APPLY openjson(value) WITH 
   (proclaim_id int '$.proclaim_id',
   test_patient_id int  '$.test_patient_id') 
    
update pta                             
  set proclaim_id= pis.proclaim_id                  
from proclaim_test_adf2 pta    
join #ProclaimIDs pis on pis.testPatientID=pta.test_id
```

Comment: Edit the question to format the code properly. Where do you have this stored procedure? Is it Azure SQL database?

Comment: yes, its in azure sql database

Answer (score 0):

- The variables `@var1 and @var2` are not being assigned the proper values during stored procedure call and hence the temporary tables are not getting populated properly and the `proclaim_test_adf2` is not getting updated properly.

- Also, the value passed to the stored procedure should be as shown below:

```
[{"proclaim_id":1,"test_patient_id":1},{"proclaim_id":2,"test_patient_id":2},{"proclaim_id":3,"test_patient_id":3},{"proclaim_id":4,"test_patient_id":4},{"proclaim_id":5,"test_patient_id":1},{"proclaim_id":6,"test_patient_id":2},{"proclaim_id":7,"test_patient_id":3},{"proclaim_id":8,"test_patient_id":4}]
```

- Now the stored procedure code would be:

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[UpdateProclaimIDs_test_adf2]                                                                                                  
       @p_request_string  nvarchar(max)                                                                                                 
AS                                                                                                  
 BEGIN    
     
  declare @var1 nvarchar(max)= JSON_query(@p_request_string,'$')

  --drop table #temp2
   SELECT value
   into #temp2
   FROM OPENJSON(@var1)

     create table #ProclaimIDs    
  (testPatientID int,proclaim_id int) 

  insert into #ProclaimIDs(testPatientID,proclaim_id)
   select test_patient_id,proclaim_id
   from #temp2 
   CROSS APPLY openjson(value) WITH 
   (proclaim_id int '$.proclaim_id',
   test_patient_id int  '$.test_patient_id') 
    
update proclaim_test_adf2                            
  set proclaim_id= pis.proclaim_id                  
from proclaim_test_adf2  
join #ProclaimIDs pis on pis.testPatientID=proclaim_test_adf2.test_id

end
```

- The following is the starting data I have taken for  `proclaim_test_adf2`.

[image]

- The following is the pipeline JSON for stored procedure activity:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Stored procedure1",
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[UpdateProclaimIDs_test_adf2]",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "p_request_string": {
                            "value": {
                                "value": "[{\"proclaim_id\":1,\"test_patient_id\":1},{\"proclaim_id\":2,\"test_patient_id\":2},{\"proclaim_id\":3,\"test_patient_id\":3},{\"proclaim_id\":4,\"test_patient_id\":4},{\"proclaim_id\":5,\"test_patient_id\":1},{\"proclaim_id\":6,\"test_patient_id\":2},{\"proclaim_id\":7,\"test_patient_id\":3},{\"proclaim_id\":8,\"test_patient_id\":4}]",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "sqldb",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]

- The `proclaim_test_adf2` table also gets updated as per requirement.

[image]